# how can i use brackets intead of full code in php

Tags: php

suppose i have a variable in a seperate php file i.e

```
$imgfile = "images/img.jpg";
```

now i have a php file where i am including a html or another php file i.e

```
<?php 
include("foo.html");
?>
```

and in foo.html i have the following code..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>foo site</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="<?php echo $imgfile; ?>">
```

and it is works but i am including that $imgfile many times so i want not to type 
`<?php echo $imgfile; ?>` again and again.. i have seen many scripts that include such files by just typing `{$imgfile}` but i don't know how to use it please let me know how can i use such a format..??

Comment: I'm sorry by reading your question I though <?php echo $imgfile; ?> does not work, as you have it placed inside *.html file. Which should not work. Can you clarify more about what you are looking for?

Comment: noop i am including that html file in php file so <?php ?> is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP **is** a template engine already.
so, it has shorter form for `echo` statement, especially for this purpose:

```
<?=$imgfile?>
```

considerable shorter and comparable to `{$imgfile}`

Note that to make use of brackets, you'll have to devise alternatives for loops, conditions and other statements, which will complicate your life. 
while using PHP as a template, you'll be able to use built-in PHP operators, like `foreach` or `if` or include.

So, it would be better to stick to `<?=$imgfile?>` syntax.

Just make sure you have `short_open_tags` setting turned on

Answer (score 0):

I think Smarty, a templating engine, is what you are looking for. See this link: http://smarty.net/

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this behavior you should use a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or write your own interpreter that will replace such expressions with the appropriate values.

e.g.

```
$buffer = 'Hello {$world}';
$world = "World";

if(preg_match_all("/{([^}]+)}/im", $buffer, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $expression = $match[0];
        $exactMatch = $match[1];

        if(defined($exactMatch)) {
            $buffer = str_replace($expression, constant($exactMatch), $buffer);
        } else {


            if(strrpos($exactMatch, "$") !== false) {
                $vars = get_defined_vars();
                $var = str_replace("$", "", $exactMatch);
                if(isset($vars[$var])) {
                    $buffer = str_replace($expression, $vars[$var], $buffer);
                }
            }

            if(is_callable($exactMatch)) {
                $buffer = str_replace($expression, call_user_func($exactMatch), $buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $buffer;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are three options for you here.

1) assign `<img src="<?php echo $imgfile; ?>">` to a shorter string

```
 $a = "<img src='$imgfile'>";
```

Then in your templates

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>foo site</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <img src="<?php echo $imgfile; ?>">
```

2) Use a placeholder then buffer and post process your output.

In your templates

```
 <?php echo ob_start('myReplacementCallback') ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>foo site</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 {{imgfile}}
 <?php ob_end_flush (); ?>
```

Define `myReplacementCallback` somewhere:

```
function myReplacementCallback($contents) {
    $replacements = array(
        '{{imgfile}}' => "<img src='/path/to/image'>",
    );

    return str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $contents);
}
```

3) Use a template engine like [twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) or smarty. (**Prefered method**)

Comment: 2 of 3 methods has serious design flaws. and third one just mentioned. is it a good answer?

Comment: despite of a typo in the first method, it spoils whole idea of templates. ALL html code should be present in the template. By adding HTML to the controller code, you split HTML between business logic and presentation and make it worse than if was before. and in the second one there is not a single reason to interpret a TEXT file as PHP code, catch buffers and then process. you can just READ it from the disk and process.